# How to assign control n to bind any readline function

Tags: bash, readline

Tried to assign control n to bind any readline function in bash but can't, e.g:

```
bind '"\C-n" : previous-history'
```

but still work as  `bind -x '"\C-n" : "echo foo"'`

Why and how to solve it?

Comment: Try `bind '"\C-n": previous-history'`, without no space before `:`. This is not an answer because I cannot answer "why?".

Comment: Shouldn't Ctrl-N be `next-history`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kamil Maciorowski said
Try bind `'"\C-n":  previous-history'`

without any space **before** `:`

While it's fine to have space after `:`